# MSI MsiGetFeatureState returns INSTALLSTATE_BROKEN when called by a custom action as commit execution

Tags: wix, windows-installer

One of my CA's tried to detect which feature was selected using **MsiGetFeatureState** and modify HKLM using its state, but it alayws returns **INSTALLSTATE_BROKEN**. I put this CA before "**InstallFinalize**".

So I wonder if this is expected and how I can do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention. If I change it to "immediate" execution, MsiGetFeatureState returns the correct value, but in that case, I can't add the reg key in HKLM when UAC is on.

Comment: I would also like to post an answer that helped my specific situation in InstallShield. This may not apply exactly to wix, but the question proposed directly applies to my problem. My InstallScript had a typo in the feature name it was trying to get the state of. So I was getting `INSTALLSTATE_BROKEN` (which has a numeric value of 0, FYI). It was a silly problem, but stumped me none-the-less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [Obtaining Context Information for Deferred Execution Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

A deferred cusom acton ( which commit is ) can't call MsiGetFeatureState.   Only an immeadiate custom action can.  If the information is needed in the deferred it must be marshaled using CustomActionData.  For more information, read [Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/).

Also please realize that commit custom actions don't execute when rollback is disabled.

I'm not really sure what you mean by "modify HKLM using it's state"  but in general you should use the registry table to declare registry updates.  Don't reinevent the wheel as it's generally less robust.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid modify the features in the registry. i'm not sure if it's allowed to query feature states thru the api while installing the same product. you may get an old/wrong answer. but what you can do, is to set some property's and use them within the custom action. Take a look at the msdn "Conditional Statement Syntax". there are some symbols which allow you the query features-actions and feature-states (or components).